# drawing a symbol within a tikz node style

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to define some nodes, which will inlcude a standard symbol inside a rectangle node:

```
\tikzset{ remember picture,
   SYMBOL/.style = {rectangle,
                    line width=1pt,
                    draw,align=center,
                    label={below:#1},
   },
}
```

and this should be inside the node-text:

```
   \draw[line width=0.7pt] (-0.2,-0.2)--(-0.05,-0.2)--(0.05,0.2)--(0.2,0.2)
                           (-0.2,0)--(0.2,0);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Will this be the case for *every* `SYMBOL` node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can box the symbol and then use the box inside the `\node` text; boxing  the symbol will prevent it from inhering undesired settings for the containing `tikzpicture`; if this is not required, a simple `\newcommand` might be used instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{ remember picture,
   SYMBOL/.style = {rectangle,
                    line width=1pt,
                    draw,align=center,
                    label={below:#1},
   },
}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
\tikz\draw[line width=0.7pt] (-0.2,-0.2)--(-0.05,-0.2)--(0.05,0.2)--(0.2,0.2)
                           (-0.2,0)--(0.2,0);%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[SYMBOL=text] {\usebox\mybox};
\node[SYMBOL=text,fill=cyan] at (2,0) {\usebox\mybox};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If every SYMBOL node should contain the given symbol, then you can do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{ remember picture,
   SYMBOL/.style = {rectangle,
    line width=1pt,
    draw,
    align=center,
    label={below:#1},
    label={center:\usebox\mybox},
    minimum size=20pt
   },
}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
\tikz\draw[line width=0.7pt] (-0.2,-0.2)--(-0.05,-0.2)--(0.05,0.2)--(0.2,0.2)
                           (-0.2,0)--(0.2,0);%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[SYMBOL=text] {};
\node[SYMBOL=text,fill=cyan] at (2,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```